# Retrieve Sagemaker instance metrics from cloudwatch via CLI or API

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cli, amazon-cloudwatch, amazon-sagemaker

I've got a training job running on Sagemaker. I would like to retrieve instance metrics like MemoryUtilization etc by CLI or boto3 client.

Obviously I can see them in the console. However, I cannot see them in the CLI/API. For example, when running:

```
aws cloudwatch list-metrics --namespace "AWS/SageMaker"
```

I can see only metrics regarding endpoint invocation but not any training job related metrics.

Any idea?

Thanks!